# android (Advanced)Saving a Bitmap Canvas with DrawText but textsize calculation needed

Tags: android, canvas, drawtext

I have a Canvas that i draw text on.
(this is quite advanced i think hope you can follow me)

See attached image below.

The functionality is that I can tap on the screen to change the textsize.
Tap left screen = smaller Font.
Tap right Screen = bigger Font.
I can then also move the text on the screen.

When textsize is ok and i have moved the text where i want it,
Then I want to save it back to the original Bitmap.

I use `options.inSampleSize = 4;` to initially load the `Bitmap`

The ImageView that have the Bitmap is of course smaller then the original Image.
Some kind of calculation is needed.
This tends to be quite difficult to do.

I have the `options.inSampleSize = 4` Bitmaps Ratio.
It's 0.59, 0.69 something depending on Landscape or portrait.

Im playing around with that to somehow change the new Bitmap`setTextSize`
 to look the same as the ImageView smaller Bitmap.

What could i do here?
I have a feeling that since one never know what size an image have.
I have to somehow scale/constrain the Loaded Bitmap Ratio to a fixed Ratio.

Then i need to using percentage or something to transfer the text location
to the bigger image.
I can kind of do that when it comes to initial 
(red small ball on picture) location. Hence,  the starting point of the text.

But i dont know how long the text is so im stuck so so speak and asking for advice

One way i tried was to divide `paint.getTextSize()` with the Ratio something like 0.59. That looked like a solution at first. But the image ratio is not fixed and the Font size is not fixed something else is needed.

Here are two pictures showing the problem.

On phone Bitmap:

[image]

The saved new Bitmap:

[image]

Comment: This question was to hard i think. I have not solved it, but thinking about makeing limitations like fixed font size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear that I understand what you mean, but here's a go. It sounds like you were close to the right approach. Instead of using a fixed ratio, you need to calculate the ratio that the image is scaled by to fit in the view on the phone, then you can scale the text by the inverse ratio. So in steps:

- Measure the width of the original image (height would do just as well, but we just need one dimension)
- Measure the width of the scaled image
- Calculate ratio (`ratio = original / scaled`)
- Let the user type their text
- You can then get the text size using something like: `float paintSize = paint.getTextSize();`
- For rendering on the final image, use `paint.setTextSize(paintSize / ratio);`.

Comment: Thanks and finally an answer. Will give it a go in a few hours. That sounds like something i have not tried :)

Comment: it's working so good. I cannot believe it's working thanks again. It even work when i set each pentext to different size and Font.

Comment: I made a follow/new question here now when this part is solved thanks to @kabuko http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376414/android-how-to-load-save-original-size-bitmap-with-no-outofmemory

Comment: @Erik please post your answer.