# android how to load/save original size Bitmap with no OutOfMemory

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I read many discussions about the inSampleSize OutOfMemory dilemma.
Cannot get a good solution so i ask a question about it.
Im currently loading a bitmap with inSampleSize=4.
That will give me a Bitmap with the size 648x388.
Original On disk size is 2592x1592.

Im writing text on 648x388 bitmap and saving it back to disk.
Im writing on the 648x388 because the 2592x1592 give me OutOfMemory .

The way it works is that there can be 1-10 648x388 Bitmaps to be saved in a `while` loop.
I want to change this loop to save 1-10 2592x1592 Bitmaps.

How can i securely load the 2592x1592?
I don care about the resolution going down 60% or more.
As long as the Bitmap has the same size 2592x1592.
Is there a way to maybe keep the size but make Bitmap thinner,
removing color without making quality bad.

My first thought was going something like this to get the biggest bitmap i could get:
I have not tested this but get a feeling it's a bad way

```
boolean work = true;
int insample = 2;
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
while(work){
    try{
    options.inSampleSize = insample;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options);
        work = false;
    }catch(Exception e){
        insample++;
    }
}
```

any help would be grate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image processing requires a lot of memory. you cant use the whole bitmap and just modify it on your phone. use a web service for that. upload, process, download. sorry there is no other way a decoded bitmap just takes a lot of memory.

And by the way you cant catch an outOFMemory Exception. the app just crashes.

Comment: Thanks @DArkO for answer. Interesting.. If i cannot use a web service is there some way to make the Bitmap thinner but keep the same size 2592x1592. Guess i have to load it anyway and that hitting the OOM.

Comment: well the resolution is actually how many pixels there are in a bitmap (one dimension is how many pixels are there in a single line width and in height respectively). so the bitmap object holds all the pixels it has. by reducing the size, you reduce the number of pixels and that reduces the resolution. its simple. i have worked with images and there is no way to process large images without memory usage (think software like photoshop, it expensive to the processor and RAM memory, imagine fitting that kind of thing into 16 megabytes of memory, its just not possible.. sorry)

Comment: Thanks for your incite.
must find some android library api that can access the bitmap on the sdcard and shopping of some resolution. That should not be to hard i guess

Comment: what exactly will that achieve. you cant modify an image on the sd card. what will process that image? its like saying you can get your usb memory stick to process an image for you on its own??? the only thing you can do is process a smaller (resampled) image of yours and save that one. or make a web service to which you will upload process and download. there isn't a workaround..

Comment: I was not clear on one thing. I don care about the resolution going down 60% or more. As long as the Bitmap has the same size 2592x1592.
If i can remove every second pixel on the bitmap and then load it with BitmapFactory. Does that make sence?

Comment: no it doesn't. 2592x1592 <-- This 2 numbers represent resolution. if you scale down the resolution by 60 percent this means now you will be working with an image that has 60 percent less pixels which is equal to a 60 percent smaller resolution which should get you an image that is: 1034x636. you dont get an image that is the same resolution but smaller. where is the logic in that? the resolution defines the size. it defines how much memory the image occupies.

Comment: well im glad i could clear things up a bit for you. :). take care.

Comment: There has to be a way to see how much memory i have to my disposal, before i try the BitmapFactory.decodeFile. avoding the the OOM right?

Comment: yes there is. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29. But just remember that this gives you the total memory. you still need to account for your memory usage, and also keep in mind that bitmap content is not shown in the heap, its in the native memory pre android 3.0 but it is still calculated. this means you might not be seeing a large heap but seeing the app still running out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

There's a hard limit on process size in Android and a 4 mega-pixel image at four bytes a pixel will hit it all by itself (on many devices), without any room for your program.

I think you are going to need to do one of two things: Create a web service to do the image processing on a server/in the cloud; or learn to do your image processing "on-the-fly" by manipulating the data directly instead of using a bitmap.

Comment: Thanks @antlersoft, The "on-the-fly" manipulating could be my solution here. Maybe i can on the SdCard manipulate the bitmap to make it smaller but keeping the size. What you think?